# Parse nested JSON values and display in recyclerview while sorting date wise

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, android-recyclerview

So I have to parse the following JSON and display the data in a two step recycler view, that is, at first screen the app should only display the Associate name and Amount,

[image: something like this]

But if I click over some list item, it should display the rest of the data too.

Also, I know that I would have to create a Model class for my response which implements the Comparable interface.

This class will override `compareTo` method which will gonna sort the transaction based on the `transaction_date`.
But I am at loss understanding the whole process because when I generate my POJO classes, I get four different java classes (Transaction, Datum , Card, Associate). And while I was creating the adapter for the recyclerview I was not able to access the `"amount"` field directly because it is present in another class.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "status_code": "200",
    "data": [
        {
            "transaction_id": "2",
            "transaction_date": "2018-04-19 05:27:23.0",
            "amount": "200.00",
            "user_id": "2",
            "currency": "MXN",
            "associate_id": "1",
            "associate": {
                "is_active": "N",
                "associate_type": "Autoservicio",
                "name": "alsuper",
                "created_date": "12-Feb-2018 07:31:58 AM",
                "associate_id": "1",
                "url": null,
                "last_update_date": "12-Feb-2018 07:31:58 AM"
            },
            "card_id": "2",
            "card": {
                "bank_code": "002",
                "is_active": "Y",
                "allows_charges": "Y",
                "card_number": "411111XXXXXX1111",
                "openpay_card_id": "kiusphu8moqri6qys7sg",
                "type": "debit",
                "card_id": "2",
                "expiration_year": "21",
                "user_id": "2",
                "expiration_month": "10",
                "bank_name": "bank name",
                "created_date": "21-Mar-2018 05:46:58 AM",
                "brand": "visa",
                "last_update_date": "21-Mar-2018 05:46:58 AM",
                "holder_name": "name name name name"
            }
        }
   ]
}
```

I am happy to share the adapter classes, right now I didn't share is because I would like to get some fresh perspective over the problem.

**Update 1**

So after applying  Raja Jawahar's solution i was able to run once, but after making the final changes, the following situation has arrived.

```
D/1: Loaded View
D/2: Loaded recycler View
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=22KB, data=30KB
       After code cache collection, code=22KB, data=30KB
       Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://URL http/1.1
          --> END GET
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (No such file or directory)
W/ImageView: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: 
D/OkHttp: <-- 200  http:URL (757ms)
          Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
          Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With
          Content-Type: application/json
          Content-Length: 4109
D/OkHttp: Date: Sun, 15 Jul 2018 13:42:20 GMT
D/OkHttp: {"status":"success","status_code":"200","data": DATA]}
          <-- END HTTP (4109-byte body)
D/6: Passing to Adapter Failure
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

My supporting code is as follows,

**Fragment**

```
TransactionAssociate = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        transactionsAdapter = new TransactionsAdapter(getContext(), TransactionAssociate);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(transactionsAdapter);
        Log.d("2", "Loaded recycler View");
        APIInterface apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
        Call<List<Transactions>> call = apiInterface.getTransactionList(sharedPreferences.getString(UNIQUE_ID, "qwe"));
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Transactions>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Transactions>> call, Response<List<Transactions>> response) {

                TransactionAssociate = response.body();
                Log.d("5", "Passing to Adapter");
                try {
                    transactionsAdapter.setTransactionsList(TransactionAssociate);
                    Log.d("4", "Passed to Adapter");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Transactions>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("6", "Passing to Adapter Failure", t);
            }
        });
```

**Http Interface**

```
@GET("URL")
Call<List<Transactions>>getTransactionList(@Path(value = "user_id",encoded = true)String user_id);
```

**Adapter**

```
public class TransactionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TransactionsAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    private Context context;
    private List <Transactions> TransactionsList;


    public TransactionsAdapter(Context context, List<Transactions> TransactionsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.TransactionsList = TransactionsList;
    }

    public void setTransactionsList(List<Transactions> transactionsList){
        this.TransactionsList = transactionsList;

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public TransactionsAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TransactionsAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Transactions transactionsList = TransactionsList.get(position);
        Transactions.DataEntity dataEntity = transactionsList.getData().get(0);
        holder.associateName.setText(dataEntity.getAssociate().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

**Transactions.class**

```
public class Transactions {

@SerializedName("data")
private List<DataEntity> data;
@SerializedName("status_code")
private String statusCode;
@SerializedName("status")
private String status;

public List<DataEntity> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<DataEntity> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public static class DataEntity {
    @SerializedName("card")
    private CardEntity card;
    @SerializedName("card_id")
    private String cardId;
    @SerializedName("associate")
    private AssociateEntity associate;
    @SerializedName("associate_id")
    private String associateId;
    @SerializedName("currency")
    private String currency;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("amount")
    private String amount;
    @SerializedName("transaction_date")
    private String transactionDate;
    @SerializedName("transaction_id")
    private String transactionId;
}

public static class CardEntity {
    @SerializedName("holder_name")
    private String holderName;
    @SerializedName("last_update_date")
    private String lastUpdateDate;
    @SerializedName("brand")
    private String brand;
    @SerializedName("created_date")
    private String createdDate;
    @SerializedName("bank_name")
    private String bankName;
    @SerializedName("expiration_month")
    private String expirationMonth;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("expiration_year")
    private String expirationYear;
    @SerializedName("card_id")
    private String cardId;
    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("openpay_card_id")
    private String openpayCardId;
    @SerializedName("card_number")
    private String cardNumber;
    @SerializedName("allows_charges")
    private String allowsCharges;
    @SerializedName("is_active")
    private String isActive;
    @SerializedName("bank_code")
    private String bankCode;
}

public static class AssociateEntity {
    @SerializedName("last_update_date")
    private String lastUpdateDate;
    @SerializedName("associate_id")
    private String associateId;
    @SerializedName("created_date")
    private String createdDate;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("associate_type")
    private String associateType;
    @SerializedName("is_active")
    private String isActive;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DTO Generator(Android Plugin to create a Model Class)

Create a class like below for your Response

```
public class DataModel {

  @SerializedName("data")   private List<Data> data;   @SerializedName("status_code")   private String status_code;   @SerializedName("status")   private String status;
     public static class Data {
    @SerializedName("card")
    private Card card;
    @SerializedName("card_id")
    private String card_id;
    @SerializedName("associate")
    private Associate associate;
    @SerializedName("associate_id")
    private String associate_id;
    @SerializedName("currency")
    private String currency;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private String user_id;
    @SerializedName("amount")
    private String amount;
    @SerializedName("transaction_date")
    private String transaction_date;
    @SerializedName("transaction_id")
    private String transaction_id;   }

  public static class Card {
    @SerializedName("holder_name")
    private String holder_name;
    @SerializedName("last_update_date")
    private String last_update_date;
    @SerializedName("brand")
    private String brand;
    @SerializedName("created_date")
    private String created_date;
    @SerializedName("bank_name")
    private String bank_name;
    @SerializedName("expiration_month")
    private String expiration_month;
    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private String user_id;
    @SerializedName("expiration_year")
    private String expiration_year;
    @SerializedName("card_id")
    private String card_id;
    @SerializedName("type")
    private String type;
    @SerializedName("openpay_card_id")
    private String openpay_card_id;
    @SerializedName("card_number")
    private String card_number;
    @SerializedName("allows_charges")
    private String allows_charges;
    @SerializedName("is_active")
    private String is_active;
    @SerializedName("bank_code")
    private String bank_code;   }

  public static class Associate {
    @SerializedName("last_update_date")
    private String last_update_date;
    @SerializedName("associate_id")
    private String associate_id;
    @SerializedName("created_date")
    private String created_date;
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("associate_type")
    private String associate_type;
    @SerializedName("is_active")
    private String is_active;   } }
```

Access your DataModel in your Adapter like below

```
package com.mobieadz.sales;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyRecylerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecylerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

  private Context context;
  private List<Data> datas = new ArrayList<>();

  @NonNull @Override
  public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent,
      int viewType) {
    return null;
  }

  public MyRecylerViewAdapter(Context context, List<DataModel> dataModels) {
    this.context = context;
    this.dataModels = dataModels;
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

   Data data = datas.get(position);
    youtextView.setText(data.amount);
    yourtextView.setText(data.associate.name)
    yourtextView.setText(data.associate.name)

  }

  @Override public int getItemCount() {
return dataModels.size();
  }

  public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @SiddhantGhosh Problem with your Transaction class, I think.. Can u please post the Transaction class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176012/discussion-between-siddhant-ghosh-and-raja-jawahar).